# android - java.lang.RuntimeException: view android.widget.RelativeLayout being added, but it already has a parent

Tags: android

i got this error while doing this.

java.lang.RuntimeException: view android.widget.RelativeLayout being added, but it already has a parent

this error came on last line. where i am adding RelativeLayout in WindowManager.

```
 windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

         final WindowManager.LayoutParams paramt = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

                paramt.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
                paramt.x = 0;
                paramt.y = chatHead.getHeight();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "height: "+chatHead.getHeight(), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                setContentView(R.layout.r_convo);
                r_convo = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.r_convo);

                windowManager.addView(r_convo, paramt);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have called `setContentView(R.layout.r_convo)`. That automatically attaches the view to the active window of the app. Hence, the error.

Every application's layout will always be attached to a `Window` object. Instead of instantiating a new one, you should acquire a reference to the current active Window via `Activity.getWindow()`, then alter its behavior using setters like `Window.setFlag()`

Comment: can you please tell me how can I do it. please give me some code. thanks.